# How to send app invitaion to facebook friends (Non Game App).?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. I had listed facebook friends and send app invitation(from facebook send request dialog)!
   My question is can i send request without using facebook send request dialog and if yes how ?
   My code is below if i don`t supply ids to (WebRequestDialog) .setTo("id of friends in comma seperated") then  i am not able to send requests ,but if i  supply ids of friends then facebook native dialog to send request opens and request sent successfully.

facebookFriendsDetail is taggable friends list which i got from taggable friends api.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            int USE_FRIEND_SIZE;
            if(facebookFriendsDetail.size()>49)
            {
                USE_FRIEND_SIZE=49;
            }else
            {
                USE_FRIEND_SIZE=facebookFriendsDetail.size();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < USE_FRIEND_SIZE; i++) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    sb.append(facebookFriendsDetail.get(i).getId().toString());
                } else {
                    sb.append(","
                            + facebookFriendsDetail.get(i).getId().toString());
                }

            }
            // params.putString("to", sb.toString());
            params.putString("message",
                    "Join CConnect To feel Better Experience Of Meetings And Calls");

            WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                    getActivity(), Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                    .setTheme(
                            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen).setTo(sb.toString())
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                final String requestId = values
                                        .getString("request");
                                if (requestId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }).build();
            requestsDialog.show();
```

2.my app is not a game app, i forcefully added a canvas framework and after it i was able to send app request , Now my question is how does redirection work here, i want if someone open this request notification in facebook mobile app it redirect it to my app if installed if not redirect it to playstore link.

And for web app i want it to redirect it to app page that i created in facebook.

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a current hole in the Facebook API regarding web invites to non-game canvas apps. The Facebook API changelog from v 2.2 to v 2.3 states that the apprequests function that opens the Request Dialog is now only limited to games, and that non-game apps should use App Invites. However, App Invites work only in iOS and Android.
So currently, there is no way for users to invite friends to a non-game canvas app via the web, except by using the Send Dialog which is a lousy user experience and really shouldn't be used for that.
I have filed a bug report with Facebook and they have acknowledged it is a valid bug. Let's hope they fix it soon.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/895531977178531

Answer (score 1):

[`taggable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends) is for tagging friends, not for inviting them. You will only get tagging tokens with that one, not user IDs, that´s probably why it does not work.

For inviting, there is [`invitable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends). Make sure to read the docs carefully:

> The Invitable Friends API is only available to apps classified as Games, which also have a Canvas presence. This API is not available in v1.0. It may be called by mobile games as long as they also have a Canvas presence.

Btw, the recommended way for inviting friends in an Android App that is not a game would be the Send/Share Dialogs, for example. This part of the docs may be interesting for you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#sharingmobile

Comment: Yes i was getting encrypted id of users in taggable friends api, thats why it is going wrong. Is there a way to send invitation wihout send share dialog. Because i had used send share dialog and my client does not need this.

Comment: you can try with invitable_friends, but as it is written in the docs it´s for games. you can just invoke the app requests dialog though, without using any user ids.